# Getting SSH output "as it happens" via PHP?

Tags: php

I've used libraries like Fabric (Python) to perform various tasks on a remote server. When I run tasks via this library, I get the output from the remote server as the actions are happening. For example, if the task is executing a `git pull` on the server, I get the line by line output of that as it happens.

However, when I look at the various PHP SSH libs and the SSH2 extension. It appears there is only a way to get ALL of the output of from the command after it has already happened, in one long string. I would like to be fed output back from the remote server as the task is running. Is this possible? In pseudocode, this is kind of what I'm looking for:

```
Server::run('git pull origin master', function($output)
{
     echo $output.PHP_EOL;
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got this working. You can just read the stream returned by `ssh2_exec` using `fgets` in a loop.

Comment: Update your question too if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `flush()` after every echo

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: every found that to be reliable, but may be worth a try.